# 4.4 Update (Sprint Galaxy S3) disabled pattern lock, can i reenable?

Tags: updates, 4.4-kitkat, troubleshooting, pattern-lock

This morning I applied the 4.4 update on my Galaxy S3 (Sprint). I noticed that I can no longer use a pattern lock. The message: "Turned off by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage" is shown for Pattern, Swipe, Face unlock, Face and voice, and None.

I thought that this might be related to my work email, which I get on my phone and is exchange, but i removed all device administrators and nothing changed.

How do I re-enable pattern lock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Settings
2. Select Security
3. Under Credential Storage select 'Clear Credentials'